# DateTime TypeConverter

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, typeconverter

I have the below code to convert a string to the type T. It works fine for all other types but gives an error when T is of type DateTime.

```
TypeConverter c = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof (T) );
 return (T) c.ConvertTo( obj, typeof (T) )
```

I pass in a string like

```
obj =  "09/09/2009"
```

It throws an error {"'DateTimeConverter' is unable to convert 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'."}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know you're getting a string, you can use `TypeConverter.ConvertFromString` instead. That works with `DateTimeConverter`, although I don't know why `ConvertTo` doesn't.

For instance, this works:

```
TypeConverter c = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof (DateTime) );
Console.WriteLine((DateTime) c.ConvertFromString("09/09/2009"));
```

Alternatively, just `ConvertFrom` works as well:

```
TypeConverter c = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof (DateTime) );
Console.WriteLine((DateTime) c.ConvertFrom("09/09/2009"));
```

It's going to convert *to* a `DateTime` because that's the kind of converter it is.

You should be careful of cultural issues though.