# Convert DateTime with TypeDescriptor.GetConverter.ConvertFromString (using custom format)

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there any way to make

`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter.ConvertFromString` convert to `DateTime` using a custom format e.g. "`2011-04-21 13-03-56`"?

If not, is there any DateTime-format out there that can be applied to a folder name (/,\,:,etc. are not allowed as you know)?

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance
Random-I-Am

Edit:

Since my request still seems to not be understood correctly I am again trying to elaborate on my question. My users are creating folders with specific names. For example "1000_Link_Topic1_2011-01-25 14-12-10". They are free to combine their information as they like and omit information where needed. They don't even have to care about case sensitivity. So I could face another folder named "1000_link_Topic2".

What I have is a single class with a single property for each possible fragment of information. In this case I would have (Since I had to find a way of checking each properties default value regardless of the property type I am using nullable types):

```
Short? short_val;
EContentType? enum_val;
String string_val;
DateTime? datetime_val;
```

My code obviously splits the folder name at "_" and then tells for each fragment to which of the above property types it belongs. As soon as I know the corresponding type I am trying to convert to the Type, lets say t, using `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t).ConvertFromString(info_frag[i])`. I hope you now understand why I cannot use another conversion Method.

The code works for all the types mentioned above. My problem is to find a custom DateTime format that can be used on a folder name. All of the formats I know are using colons to separate hours from minutes and seconds.

What I want is a way to convert **from** a custom DateTime-format **to** a DateTime-object using `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter.ConvertFromString`. If that is not possible I either need to find a standard DateTime-format which can be assigned as a folder name without any further conversion or somehow extend the built-in DateTime-formats by my custom format. If it is going to be the latter I do not care about being able to use seconds or minutes. Hours will do the job.

Thanks again for being as patient as you are and helping me out with this one. Feel free to ask as many further questions as you like. I hope you can help me getting this one to work.

Random-I-Am

Comment: What should be the output format for your date time

Comment: In fact I really don't care about what format I am using. My only restriction is that I can use it and apply it to a folder name.

Comment: Do u need seconds to be in the folder name

Comment: No, I could live with it if second were not providable.

Comment: Please elaborate: Which type do you want to convert to which type?

Comment: Post the code that you tried it may help us to code better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have looked into your problem a little and found that the standard DateTimeTypeConverter uses DateTime.Parse internally which doesn't listen to CurrentCulture info at all. Instead you can trick the conversion process with your own TypeConverter!

I do not know how to attach the new typeconverter to the existing DateTime structure, if you even can, so I made a miniture AdvancedDateTime structure .. which is empty. Noone said your custom TypeConvert should even return such a thing! This one returns a regular DateTime. I provided the code below:

```
public class CustomDateTimeTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", culture);
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeTypeConverter))]
struct AdvancedDateTime
{
}

[TestFixture]
public class DateTime
{
    [Test]
    public void TypeConvert_StrangeFormat_ConvertsWithoutProblem()
    {
        string datetime = "2011-04-21 23-12-13";
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof (AdvancedDateTime) );
        var convertedFromString = converter.ConvertFromString(datetime);
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2011,4,21, 23,12,13), convertedFromString);
    }
}
```

Comment: -, this converts a `DateTime` to a `string` which was not asked!

Comment: I think he didn't read my edit. Without the edit this would have been a valuable answer. So thanks for your contribution anyways.

Comment: @Andreas: Thank you for pointing that out! I corrected my answer, also taking in mind the edits.

Comment: I need to use a TypeDescriptot.GetConverter.Convert.. method since I don't know to which types I have to convert to.

Comment: Jon Skeet answers your questions about the TypeConverter and DateTime in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174191/datetime-typeconverter . That should help!

Comment: @Jaapjan: This solution is of no help since I already discovered that I should use ConvertFromString as you can see in my question above. The problem is that the function is not able to convert from a custom DateTime-format

Comment: Altered my answer .. completely! Have a look at the new code.

Comment: @Jaapjan: Looks promising. I will have a look at this as I have some free time. Still though, as you have already mentioned, it would be awesome to directly extend DateTime or TypeConverter. Another use case for static extension methods...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 string m_strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
 m_strDate = m_strDate.Replace("/", "");
```

Append this `m_strDate` to your folder

A sample i used for text file is as follows

```
strPath += "/FileHeader_" + m_strDate + ".txt";
```

Check this sample

```
DateTime dt=new DateTime(1990,5,6);
Console.WriteLine(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dt).ConvertTo(dt, typeof(string)));
string myStr="1991-10-10";
Console.WriteLine(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dt).ConvertFrom(myStr));
```

The sample code i written just to display as per you need try as per your requirement

```
       string s = "Folder";
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1990, 5, 6);
        string str = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dt).ConvertTo(dt, typeof(string)).ToString();
        string myStr = "1991-10-10";
        string str1 = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dt).ConvertFrom(myStr).ToString();
        s = s + str1.Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "");
        textBox1.Text = s;
```

Comment: Add the seconds too if u needed and the change as per the required format as per you need

Comment: How would I use this approach to later convert the folder name back to a DateTime-object given the restrictions above?

Comment: @Andreas he did not asked for the conversion he just asked how to add date time to a folder name

Comment: @Dorababu: first line `Is there any way to make TypeDescriptot.GetConverter.ConvertFromString convert to DateTime using a custom format e.g. "2011-04-21 13-03-56"?`... Reading this: ConvertFromString to DateTime

Comment: @ Andreas : ofcourse i just gave him an idea and asked him to use that as per he needed

Comment: -, this converts a `DateTime` to a `string` which was not asked

Comment: @Dorababu: then you should elaborate so i can remove my downvote (which i really want to, but currently cannot, because of the 5-minute-rule :(  )

Comment: I know the conversion of the DateTime-format "yyyy-MM-dd" to DateTime works and can be done with the method I requested. But I need the format to at least supply hours (as mentioned above).

Comment: Out of the two in which one you want to apply hours let me know

Comment: @Dorababu Elaborate on the ConvertFrom() please

Comment: @Random what you need is to add datetime to your folder right

Comment: @Dorababu No I am parsing folders which have e.g. the following names: 1000_Link_2011-10-05 12-15. I do split those names at the "_" and convert each fragment to the corresponding type. Since the amount of fragments and their contents differ I have to use TypeDescriptot.GetConverter.ConvertFromString to conert the first fragment to short, the second to a enum I have and the third to a DateTime.

Comment: @Random : `The ConvertFrom method uses the Parse method of the DateTime class to convert from a string`.

Comment: @Random : can you clearly mention what output should be for the folder names

Comment: @Dorababu: I again edited my question. Please take a look. I would be glad if you were able to provide a solution

Comment: @Random : Do u need the date time to be as folder name or not